# Scaling of Schwabacher font

Tags: fonts, fontsize, scaling

I want to use the Schwabacher font from the yfonts package but unfortunately I am unable to scale it. So this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\swabfamily
Text
\end{document}
```

But when I try to change the font size using

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

or

```
\Large
```

or

```
\fontsize{12}{18}
```

I get an output which isn't typeset in Schwabacher anymore but falls back to the standard font.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your example to have an instance of the problem, and show any warnings you get in the log file. If I add a second paragraph `\Large Text` then it works for me.

Comment: It may have something to do with my installation since the example reported to work below by @egreg doesn't work for me. However, I now found out that scaling is possible when I repeat the \swabfamily command after issuing the \fontsize command

Comment: @Urs Can you add some information about your TeX distribution and also an example that doesn't work?

Comment: @egreg, you are responding faster than I can type :-). The exact example you posted below doesn't work for me. The first instance of "text" is in Schwabacher, the rest is typeset in standard font (but looks awkward). This is my first post here. (How) can I add code in the comments?

Comment: @Urs Add to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me; however, an adjustment can be made keeping into account that `yswab` is available in Type1 format, so it can be arbitrarily scaled:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareFontShape{LY}{yswab}{m}{n}{<->yswab}{}

\begin{document}
\swabfamily
Text

\Large
Text

\fontsize{36}{44}\selectfont
Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need Stephan Lehmke to read that to me! :D

Comment: I can not believe that it is a `x` letter.

Comment: Ok, now this example works for me too. I am sorry but unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the original problem myself. Thanks to all for your help. Is there a correct way to close this thread?